# Parse Push - How to Automatically Open an activity without user action on receiving a push on Android

Tags: android, push-notification, push, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

I have a requirement (android) where my app should run its main activity automatically when a push notification is received without the user clicking on notification in system tray. I am having a map where it shows current location, but in the push, i will receive a location, and i need my map in the main activity to move the camera to the currently received location on receiving the push, and alert the user with a custom sound. All this should happen without the user clicking on anything. Pls help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That would be extremely user hostile thing to do, requirements or not.

Comment: you can find all in [the documentation](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving/Android) ... have you read it?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev - This is not a general user facing app, its for internal purpose of employees..so the user should be friendly to this. :)

Comment: @Selvin i had read the documentation..but using that when a notification comes in, it does nothing but create a notification in system tray and the user needs to click on that..but i want some action to happen automatically when push is received...pls help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Parse.com documentation says:

> You can also specify an Intent to be fired in the background when the push notification is
>   received. This will allow your app to perform custom handling for the notification, and 
>   can be used whether or not you have chosen to display a system tray message. To implement 
>   custom notification handling, set the Action entry in your push notification data 
>   dictionary to the Intent action which you want to fire. Android guidelines suggest that 
>   you prefix the action with your package name to avoid namespace collisions with other 
>   running apps.

So you send push notifications in this way:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject("{\"action\": \"com.example.UPDATE_STATUS\""}));

ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setData(data);
push.sendPushInBackground();
```

Then in your AndroidManifest.xml register a broadcast receiver that will be called whenever a push notification is received with an action parameter of com.example.UPDATE_STATUS:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.UPDATE_STATUS" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In your broadcast receiver you can start a new activity:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MyActivity.class));
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, i did the same already and works well...thanks for  coming in, but could you please help me a bit more, as i am looking for enabling/disabling a button in my activity using this broadcast receiver when i recieve a push. If the app is not shown, i should bring it to foreground and enable the button, else just enable the button...i dont want two instance of same activity to be runing. Could u  pls help ?

Comment: UPDATE: Got the answer, i used LocalBroadCastManager to send a broadcast to my Activity, and in the onrecieve of the local broadcast receiver,  enabled/disabled the button. thanks everyone.

Comment: if you have more than "action", do you know how to retrieve all the other member of the JSON object ?

Answer (score 1):

warning to @makovkastar, major changes since version V1.8. for instance: no more com.example.UPDATE_STATUS.

push notifications guide is more clear now: https://www.parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

this is the ParsePushBroadcastReceiver subclass: https://gist.github.com/panchicore/97d5ad25842258576109
this answer have a good tutorial to send/receive local broadcasts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875292/155293

Basically onPushReceive will be called when a push is received in the device, in this method use LocalBroadcastManager to make something in the app, for instance, add a new message to a chatroom.